# How to bind the REST API result

Tags: rest, jsom, sharepoint-rest-api

Today I got requirement to get the list data using rest and bind to html drop down . I am getting the information by filtering it from browser

```
(_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Tabletop%20Sessions')/items?Select=Title";)
```

. As this is my first program can any one help me what's wrong in my below code in binding the data to drop-down.

```
<style type="text/css">
 .textbox{
     font-family : inherit;
     font-size   : 100%;width: 275px;
     border: 4px solid #F7F9FA;
     -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
     -moz-border-radius: 3px;
     border-radius: 3px;
     -moz-box-shadow: 2px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06) inset, 0 0 1px #95a2a7 inset;
     -webkit-box-shadow: 2px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06) inset, 0 0 1px #95A2A7 inset;
     box-shadow: 2px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.06) inset, 0 0 1px #95A2A7 inset;
     height: 30px;
     width: 275px;
     display: block;
 }
.fontsize{
    font-style: arial;font-size:17px;
}
.select{
    width: 285px;height: 25px;
}
</style>

<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js "></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">

<body>
<table>
<tr>
   <td colspan="2"><img align="right" src=" Image URL"/>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td colspan="2"><img src=""/>
</td>
</tr>

</tr>
<tr>
 <td class="fontsize">Months:</td>
 <td>
       <select id="drbfunction" class="select">
       <option selected="selected">Select</option>
       </select>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td class="fontsize"><br>Programes:</td>
 <td><br>
       <select id="drbprogrames" class="select">
       <option selected="selected">Select</option>

</tr>
</table>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js "></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.js"></script>
<script>
SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', getprogrames);
function getprogrames(sender, args)
{
    alert("in Programes");
    var userid = _spPageContextInfo.userId;
    var requestUri = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Tabletop%20Sessions')/items?Select=Title";
    var requestHeaders = { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" };
    $.ajax({
        url: requestUri,
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        headers: requestHeaders,
        success: onprogramQuerySucceeded (data) {
         var listData = data.d.results;
         var itemCount = listData.length;
         var processedCount = 0;
         var functions = document.getElementById("drbprogrames");
         for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
           {
               var option = document.createElement('option');
               option.text = option.value = result[i].Title;
               functions.add(option);
           }
      },
        error: function (data) {
           alert(failure(data));
       }
    });
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try the following please:

```
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
{
    //var option = document.createElement('option');
    //option.text = option.value = result[i].Title;
    //functions.add(option);

    $(functions).append("<option value='" + result[i].Title + "'>" + result[i].Title + "</option>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know AngularJS then I will recommend using that. It will simplify a lot of things for you.

In your case you will call REST API with `_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Tabletop%20Sessions')/items?Select=Title,ID` and store it in `$scope` variable.

```
$scope.dropDownOptions = response.data.d.results;
```

In you HTML portion you will write something like this

```
<select ng-options="item.Title for item in dropDownOptions"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are loading multiple jQuery js files in your code. Minimize it only one.
Next, Correct your REST API Select parameter to `$Select`.
Lastly, as you are using jQuery then you can simply use it following way to populate the drop down.

```
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(getPrograms, "sp.js");

function getPrograms(){
    $.ajax({
        method: "GET",
        url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('Tabletop%20Sessions')/items?$Select=Title",
        contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
        headers:{
            "Accept":"appilcation/json;odata=verbose"
        },
        success: function(data){
            var results = data.d.results;
            var options = "";
            for(var i = 0; i < results.length; i++){
                options = options + "<option value='" + results[i].Title + "'>" + results[i].Title + "</option>";
            }
            $("#drbprograms").append(options);
        },
        error: function(err){
            console.log("failed");
            console.log(err);
        }
    });
}
```